# Forwardable Identification/Authentication

Tags: oauth, kerberos, saml

Like the Kerberos tickets, is it possible to forward to another application:

- a SAML assertion
- an OAuth token

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

**SAML Assertions**: Yes, one such protocol is WS-Trust where the Security Token Service (STS) generates SAML assertions and they can be presented to an end service (i.e. relying party) that trusts the STS. Another is the "SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion Profile" for OAuth - simply, the SAML grant type - in which you can present the SAML assertion (usually got through SAML Web SSO) to the OAuth endpoint and exchange it to an Access Token.

**OAuth Tokens**: I'm not sure about a standard use case for this.